# DC voltmeter and full wave bridge rectifier in Proteus

Tags: voltage-measurement, proteus

I am trying to measure the average voltage on a resistor but I see always zero like below:

[image]

I connected ground but the result was the same.

When I add a parallel capacitor in R1, there is no problem but otherwise I can't get a good reading. My friend tried this circuit on Multisim and there was no extreme situation like I have.

Comment: Where did you connect ground?

Comment: @Andyaka I connected it near source, near R, near R1 and source but result was same.